# API restrictions specify which APIs can be called with this key

Tags: google-cloud-platform

API restrictions specify which APIs can be called with this key.
Does this list INCLUDE or EXCLUDE the API's listed?

If Geoloaction API is in the list does this mean that Gelocations can be called or that Geolocations can NOT be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **API restrictions** are used to specify the APIs that can be called with an API Key, as mentioned in the [Using API Keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#api_key_restrictions).

Based on this, the APIs that you add to the restrictions will be the ones **included** and that can be used with the key. If you add the Geolocation API in the list, that means that this API can be called by using the **API key**.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to this and found the term 'restrictions' confusing as restriction really means 'to limit or stop usage of something'. Now I know that by adding a restriction I am allowing myself access to something!

Comment: That's is correct. In this case, the restriction make reference to the only services that can interact with the key. I'm glad everything is clear now.